# Fail2ban - Exim configuration needed

Tags: fail2ban

I have seen some posts on stackexchange and other websites and have not been able to figure this out.
I am using fail2ban on Ubuntu 22 with exim, dovecot etc. for my mail server. There are some other applications on the same server as well. Since this is a private server, I wish to make my configuration quite strict and whitelist if/when necessary.

Below is what I currently have in **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/exim.conf**

```
# Fail2Ban filter for exim
#
# This includes the rejection messages of exim. For spam and filter
# related bans use the exim-spam.conf
#


[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# exim-common.local
before = exim-common.conf

[Definition]

# Fre-filter via "prefregex" is currently inactive because of too different failure syntax in exim-log (testing needed):
#prefregex = ^%(pid)s <F-CONTENT>\b(?:\w+ authenticator failed|([\w\-]+ )?SMTP (?:(?:call|connection) from|protocol(?: synchronization)? error)|no MAIL in|(?:%(host_info_pre)s\[[^\]]+\]%(host_info_suf)s>

failregex = ^%(pid)s %(host_info)ssender verify fail for <\S+>: (?:Unknown user|Unrouteable address|all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts)\s*$
            ^%(pid)s \w+ authenticator failed for (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?\[<HOST>\](?::\d+)?(?: I=\[\S+\](:\d+)?)?: 535 Incorrect authentication data( \(set_id=.*\)|: \d+ Time\(s\))?\s*$
            ^%(pid)s %(host_info)srejected RCPT [^@]+@\S+: (?:relay not permitted|Sender verify failed|Unknown user|Unrouteable address)\s*$
            ^%(pid)s SMTP protocol synchronization error \([^)]*\): rejected (?:connection from|"\S+") %(host_info)s(?:next )?input=".*"\s*$
            ^%(pid)s SMTP call from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?%(host_info)sdropped: too many (?:nonmail commands|syntax or protocol errors) \(last (?:command )?was "[^"]*"\)\s*$
            ^%(pid)s SMTP protocol error in "[^"]+(?:"+[^"]*(?="))*?" %(host_info)sAUTH command used when not advertised\s*$
            ^%(pid)s no MAIL in SMTP connection from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?%(host_info)sD=\d\S*s(?: C=\S*)?\s*$
            ^%(pid)s (?:[\w\-]+ )?SMTP connection from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?%(host_info)sclosed by DROP in ACL\s*$
            ^\s*H=(?:\S+ )?\([^)]+\) \[<ADDR>\](?: [A-Z]+=\S+){1,5} rejected RCPT$
            <mdre-<mode>>

mdre-aggressive = ^%(pid)s no host name found for IP address <HOST>$
                  ^%(pid)s no IP address found for host \S+ \(during SMTP connection from \[<HOST>\]\)$

mdre-normal =

# Parameter `mode` - `normal` or `aggressive`.
# Aggressive mode can be used to match flood and ddos-similar log-entries like:
#   'no host found for IP', 'no IP found for host'.
# Note this is not an authentication failures, so it may produce lots of false
# positives on misconfigured MTAs.
# Ex.:
#   filter = exim[mode=aggressive]
mode = normal

ignoreregex =

# DEV Notes:
# The %(host_info) defination contains a <HOST> match
```

I want to be able to permanently ban ip addresses (using fail2ban exim config) when any of the following events are found in the exim log files (mainlog and mainlog.1) in the folder **/var/log/exim4/**

```
2022-11-12 14:40:06 TLS error on connection from scanner-04.ch1.someone-abcd.com [192.1.2.3] (gnutls_handshake): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
2022-11-12 15:29:55 dovecot_plain authenticator failed for (FULLY-QUALIFIED-HOSTNAME) [192.1.2.3]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=my_host_name)
2022-11-12 20:26:17 SMTP call from [192.1.2.39] dropped: too many unrecognized commands (last was "")
2022-11-12 20:50:13 TLS error on connection from [192.1.2.3] (gnutls_handshake): An unexpected TLS packet was received.
2022-11-12 21:22:59 SMTP call from [192.1.2.55] dropped: too many syntax or protocol errors (last command was "?\b?\006?\027?\030?\031?\v?\002\001??\r?\020?\016\004\001\004\003\002\001\002\003\004\001\005\001\006\001\377\001?\001?\025\003\001?\002\002", NULL)
2022-11-12 14:30:34 TLS error on connection from scanner-27.ch1.someone-abcd.com [167.94.138.117] (gnutls_handshake): No common application protocol could be negotiated.
2022-11-12 09:32:59 TLS error on connection from hfgfydf.djddjd.io [192.168.1.2] (recv): Error in the pull function.
2022-11-12 06:29:20 H=(WIN-CLJ1B0GQ6JP) [192.168.1.2] F=<spammer@xxxy.lk> rejected RCPT <spammer@xxxy.lk>: Rejected because 192.168.1.2 is in a black list at zen.spamhaus.org
2022-11-12 00:20:22 TLS error on connection from [192.1.2.3] (gnutls_handshake): An unexpected TLS packet was received.
2022-11-12 14:31:00 SMTP call from scanner-05.ch1.someone-abcd.com [192.1.2.33] dropped: too many syntax or protocol errors (last command was "?", NULL)
```

Below is the fail2ban jail config for exim. Note, I am using Hestia if that makes any difference

```
[exim-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = exim
maxfailures = 1
bantime = -1
action   = hestia[name=MAIL]
logpath  = /var/log/exim4/mainlog
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 my_ip_address_1 my_ip_address_2 my_hostname
```

I do have some basic knowledge of regular expressions but I am struggling with finding the right ones that will suit the fail2ban exim config file.

Once I have done this for exim and verified, I wish to make similar changes for the dovecot Jail based on error message in the dovecot log as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replying here in case anyone is also interested, I finally added some regex filters above the existing ones and they seem to have been working well for a few weeks.

I think these filters may be too restrictive for at least some environments perhaps. Since this is a private email server, I am permanently banning anyone after a single violation. I have whitelisted some IP addresses (trustworthy) in the Fail2ban jail config.

````
failregex = 

## New rules that I added ##
^.*because <HOST> is in a black list at.*$
^.*Connection closed.*unsupported protocol.*user=\<\>,\srip=<HOST>.*$
^.*Connection closed \(no auth attempts in .*user=\<\>,\srip=<HOST>.*$
^.* \[<HOST>\].* The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.*$
^.* \[<HOST>\].*535 Incorrect authentication data.*$
^.* \[<HOST>\] dropped: too many .*$

##Preexisting ones##

^%(pid)s %(host_info)ssender verify fail for <\S+>: (?:Unknown user|Unrouteable address|all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts)\s*$
^%(pid)s \w+ authenticator failed for (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?\[<HOST>\](?::\d+)?(?: I=\[\S+\](:\d+)?)?: 535 Incorrect authentication data( \(set_id=.*\)|: \d+ Time\(s\))?\s*$
^%(pid)s %(host_info)srejected RCPT [^@]+@\S+: (?:relay not permitted|Sender verify failed|Unknown user|Unrouteable address)\s*$
^%(pid)s SMTP protocol synchronization error \([^)]*\): rejected (?:connection from|"\S+") %(host_info)s(?:next )?input=".*"\s*$
^%(pid)s SMTP call from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?%(host_info)sdropped: too many (?:nonmail commands|syntax or protocol errors) \(last (?:command )?was "[^"]*"\)\s*$
^%(pid)s SMTP protocol error in "[^"]+(?:"+[^"]*(?="))*?" %(host_info)sAUTH command used when not advertised\s*$
^%(pid)s no MAIL in SMTP connection from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?%(host_info)sD=\d\S*s(?: C=\S*)?\s*$
^%(pid)s (?:[\w\-]+ )?SMTP connection from (?:[^\[\( ]* )?(?:\(\S*\) )?%(host_info)sclosed by DROP in ACL\s*$
^\s*H=(?:\S+ )?\([^)]+\) \[<ADDR>\](?: [A-Z]+=\S+){1,5} rejected RCPT$ ```
````

Adding my fail2ban jail config as well

```
[exim-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = exim
maxretry = 0
maxfailures = 1
bantime = -1
findtime = 36000
action   = hestia[name=MAIL]
logpath  = /var/log/exim4/mainlog
           /var/log/exim4/mainlog.1
           /var/log/exim4/rejectlog.1
           /var/log/exim4/rejectlog
ignoreip = <<few different private IPs>>
```

Comment: I would never ban IPs forever. Your blocklist (in iptables) would become very large and slow down your system. In my experience, it's also not very useful to block single IPs for a very long time as most malicious IP addresses tend not to stay active for more than a few days.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am not sure when the system will become slow though.  `sudo ipset -L | wc -l ` gives me ~95000 and many items in the ipsets are large subnets covering a lot of IPs. System is not slow at all. I have subscribed to various feeds (e.g. abuseipdb) that update the ipsets on a daily basis. I always thought that ipsets are very fast on Linux based systems. **Note**: This fail2ban exim jail is actually not adding banned IPs to an ipset even though it looks like it should, it is in my 'to do' list.